# How to combine IFS and ISBLANK

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to create a function that measures ages and returns adult, youth, or nothing. I have some cells that don't contain ages, and I need them to return a blank value.

This function sorts the ages.
=ifs(A6 < 18,"youth", A6="", "", A6>=18,"adult")

These functions make certain cells blank.
=if(C17>=18,"adult", "")
=IF(ISBLANK(C2),,A2/B2)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try simply to start with blank case as Google Sheet identifies it as less than 18

```
=IFS(C4="","",C4<18,"youth",C4>=18,"adult")
```